# HTML button event on click and release

Tags: html, esp8266

I'm new on HTML and I need to understand some basic stuff for a project with the ESP01 wi-fi module. I would like to create a web page with a button and this one has to have a different behaviour according to if it is pressed or released.

I tried with this

```
<button onclick='location.href=&#39;/UP_ON&#39;' onmouseup='location.href=&#39;/UP_OFF&#39;'>UP</button>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is an `onmousedown` event... Of course, if it does the same thing as `onclick`, the `onmouseup` may never fire because you're changing `location.href`, causing the browser to reload the page....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

try **location.href**

```html
 <button onclick='location.href=/?UP_ON' onmouseup='location.href=/?UP_OFF'>UP</button>
```

Comment: Same thing, the problem is page reload. I'm using arduino libraries and with the server.on function the code understands when a button is pressed, but only if the page is reloaded.